# Upgrade version Of Custom Recovery

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

I have CWM already installed on my Android device.  To upgrade my CWM version, do I simply boot into fastboot and cd the new .iso over to my device?  Is it realy that simple?

EDIT -- The new file that I have is an .iso not a .zip so when I boot into CWM it doesn't see the .iso.

2nd Edit ---
I used this command when booted into fastboot to flash my recovery

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-5.0.2.0-olympus.img
```

Answer (score 0):

It's even easier than that. Just flash the new recovery from CWM as you would any other flashable zip.

Comment: see edit......I have a .iso file not a .zip file

Comment: Then that can't be a cwm recivery. What's the full file name?

Comment: recovery-clockwork-5.0.2.0-olympus.img

Comment: Seems like you have HTC. Yes you should be able to do it this way also but you might also be able find a zip of the CWM recovery for your olympus and flash that directly from CWM. So you have 2 options.

Answer (score 0):

Just flash the recovery like you flashed it before, simple as that.